# FTP in C: 331 / 530 Please specify password

Tags: c, ftp, client

I have an issue sending Pass command in C, i am writing a simple program that connects to an ftp server and prints out LIST to stdout.

```
/* -----------  SET UP CONNECTION ---------*/
//creating socket
if((sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
{
    perror("Main: Creating socket:");
    return ERROR;
}

//Zero out addr
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

//Getting host name
hPtr=gethostbyname(url.host);
if(hPtr==NULL)
{ 
    perror("Error while getting host name:");
    return ERROR;
}

//Setting up addr for connect
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)hPtr->h_addr_list[0])));

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(url.port);
if((connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))) < 0)
{
    perror("Error: Connect socket :");
    close(sock);
    return ERROR;
}

//Wait for Service ready
bzero(buffer, MAXBUF);
if(recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0)<0)
{
        perror("Error while receiving socket:");
}

printf("%s", buffer);

/* -----     LOGIN USER     -----------*/
bzero(buffer, MAXBUF);
//setup login
strcpy(buffer,"USER ");
strcat(buffer,url.user);
strcat(buffer,"\n");

//Send login
if((send(sock,buffer,MAXBUF,0))<0)
{
    perror("Error while sending socket:");
}
//Receive answer
if((recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0))<0)
{
    perror("Error while recieving socket:");
}
printf("%s", buffer);


//Send password
bzero(buffer, MAXBUF);
//setup password
strcpy(buffer,"PASS ");
strcat(buffer,url.pass);
strcat(buffer,"\n");
printf("%s",buffer);
//Send password

if((send(sock,buffer,MAXBUF,0))<0)
{
    perror("Error while sending socket:");
}
//Receive response

if((recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0))<0)
{
    perror("Error while recieving socket:");
}
printf("%s", buffer);

close(sock);
return OK;
```

Now I succesfully parse the adress I get in the launch parameter.

and I succesfully connect where I want to: I get the 220 back.

After sending
char *buffer[1024];
which contains: "USER anonymous\r\n" or "USER anonymous\n"
I get the FTP response 331 please specify the password.

after that I try to send: "PASS secret\r\n" or "PASS secret\r\n"
and I get 530

the username is anonymous and password is secret. I tested it using ftp and I could connect
am I sending the pass wrong? or am I doing the whole communication wrong?

Comment: You do get the result, so probably this C code is OK. There is no seg fault, or similar thing happening. I suspect there is something wrong with that password after all, so probably we are not able to help you.

Comment: Try sending strlen(buffer) instead of MAXBUFF characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the issue was with sending.

I need to send the exact amount of bytes apparently, so I put 
strlen(buffer) in the send() call and it started working.
The project was completed successfully. Thank you for the help.

"Try sending strlen(buffer) instead of MAXBUFF characters. –  cup 17 hours ago "

Answer (score 0):

Try using \r\n as the line end, e.g. like you write in the explanation but unlike you do in your code.

Comment: yes I have tried both, at the state I posted the code this is how it was.